# WP Query - Pagination Buttons not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, html, custom-post-type

Pagination buttons are not showing for some reason - any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, there is 8 posts showing unlike 10 as stated in the code.

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div class="container-fluid p-0 pagewrap pagehead position-relative d-table" id="recent-projects">
    <div class="container pageintro">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Recent Projects</h1>
                <p>View our recent project case studies below</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="container-fluid pt-5 pb-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'post_type=>projects&posts_per_page=10'.'&paged='.$paged );?>

            <?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="grid">
                        <figure class="effect-oscar">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array('style' => 'width: 100%; height: 200px; margin: 0px auto 15px auto;')) ?>
                            <figcaption>
                                <div class="m-auto">
                                    <h2><span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <p><span><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read Post</a>
                                </figcaption>           
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination-nav text-center m-auto d-block p-4 mx-auto my-4">
            <?php echo paginate_links( array(

                'prev_text' => '<span>Previous Page</span>',
                'next_text' => '<span>Next Page</span>'
            )); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It is a custom post type page also

Answer (score 0):

First of all your WP_Query args are incorrectly set. It should be:

```php
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'projects',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged'          => $paged
];

$catquery = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

This is the preferred way to do it by most developers. However if you wonder what is your mistake... You set the post type with arrow notation but you must use the equal sign only.: **post_type=projects**

Next your pagination doesn't know about your custom post type. You must explicitly set it:

```php
<?php 

// Need a big base number: 
$big = 999999999;

// Pagination
paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'     => $catquery->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => '<span>Previous Page</span>',
    'next_text' => '<span>Next Page</span>'
) );
```